# apply a style to a specific xml layout

Tags: android, xml

I am making an app, that has a lot of text to read, and i want it to have 2 themes. dark and light. So i think the way to do this is to have 2 `XML` layouts. But I don't know how to set a 1 `style` to 1 `laayout`, and a different `style` to a different `layout`. There is a field `android:theme` in the `manifest`, but that sets a `theme` to the whole app, and not a specific `layout`.

So, to be clear, my question is; How do you set a `style/theme` to a specific `activity` and not the whole app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest, `android:theme`  can be added to the activity tags, and those override the application tag theme.

```
<application
    android:theme="..." <!-- App theme -->

    ...
    <activity 
        android:theme="..." <!-- Theme for just this Acitivty -->
```

You can also try to programmatically call setTheme in an Activity class

> i think the way to do this is to have 2 XML layouts

You just need one layout that can pick up the attributes of the theme(s) you'll set

Comment: What do you mean "almost"

Comment: Sorry! Autocomplete on my phone ;)

Comment: Thanks. That looks like something that I can use, but can you please expand or explain a little more! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what to expand. You already know about the theme attribute in the manifest and you can clearly see the activity elements, so just add the new  attributes

Comment: So, I just add `andorid:theme` to `Activity xml?`

Comment: No. The Manifest.. `<activity android:theme="..." />`